# Biblio module not seeing Bibtex or Google Scholar Lookup option

Tags: 7

I am using biblio version 7.x-1.0-rc7 on a drupal 7.38 version site.

I am trying to do two things from the `/node/add/biblio` page:

1. Use the Google Scholar lookup to be able to get the info through the author name or book title but I don't see that option in the add content page.
2. I see online there are videos tutorials of people adding in existing bibliography data into a `BibTex` textfield - again I am not seeing that option when navigating to `/node/add/biblio`.

For some reason the only options I see is either the PubMed ID Lookup or the DOI Lookup. The publication type option just brings me to a blank biblio content where I would need to add all the date into fields not giving me an option to like just add the reference data in one text field.

This is what I see on the node add page:

[image]

This is the settings I have set on the biblio configurations page:

[image]

Any direction on how to get those options on the node add page would be greatly appreciated!